# Blender > Earth Sphere > Multiple Materials

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make an earth sphere for subsequent export to Unity.

I can do it with a single texture/material.
Works great, but I want higher resolution.
Want to have 8x4 4K tiles.

Tried UDIM. Works well in Blender.
But when I export to Unity it is a single material which accepts only 1 texture.

SO how do I create a sphere with 4x8 materials each having a 4K square texture?

Thanks in advance